# Error installing packages using conda command

Tags: python, anaconda

I have `Python 3.10` and I installed `Anaconda 3` today. I would like to install packages by `Anaconda prompt`, and I do the following for example:

```
conda install fiona
```

However, the following error appears:

`conda is not recognized as an internal command`

How to adjust this?

If I do `pip install fiona`, then it works.

What could be this error of not working the command `conda`. My system is Windows.

[image]

Comment: Do you launch "Anaconda Prompt" or a "Command Prompt" (cmd.exe)?

Comment: This usually occurs when the command is not present in any of the directory mentioned in PATH environment variable. Make sure your Anaconda installation path is added to the PATH.

Comment: @Thy, Anaconda Prompt.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Anaconda to PATH.
In my case,  anaconda installed into C:\Anaconda3. I added  C:\Anaconda3 and  C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\ to my path variable.
Set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts\

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did it, as you said. I added an image to the question for you to see. But now the error that appears after I enter `conda install fiona` is `failed to create process`. Before the error that appeared was `conda is not recognized as an internal command`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `conda` to your environment path. Otherwise your terminal/commmand prompt won't recognize the `conda` command straight away. You can check how to set environment variables and save them in your operating system [here](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment).